# Debugging multiple web application within one IIS Express site

Tags: asp.net, iis-express, application-pool, applicationhost

## The new SDK style project format no longer supports running multiple web applications inside a single website, or does it?

### Legacy project format

With the legacy project format is was possible to debug multiple website projects at once, each running in a different IIS Express application.

For example:

- http://localhost:12345 running WebApplication1
- http://localhost:12345/WebApplication2 running WebApplication2

Visual Studio takes care of `applicationhost.config`, creating a single 'website' and an 'application' per project. All 'applications' are linked to the same `Clr4IntegratedAppPool` application pool. Visual Studio starts the 'Clr4IntegratedAppPool' by launching iisexpress.exe. That all works fine.

### SDK style project format

**I cannot get the configuration described above to work for SDK style projects.** The urls have now been configured in launchSettings.json under `iisSettings/iisExpress/applicationUrl`. Again, Visual Studio alters `applicationhost.config accordingly`. The problem however is that is does't use the same application. It creates a separate application pool per project, as can be seen here:

```
<site name="WebApplication1" id="2">
  <application path="/" applicationPool="WebApplication1 AppPool">
    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\IISExpressDemo\WebApplication1" />
  </application>
  <application path="/WebApplication2" applicationPool="WebApplication2 AppPool">
    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\IISExpressDemo\WebApplication2" />
  </application>
  <bindings>
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:12345:localhost" />
  </bindings>
</site>
```

Having two application pools, requires two instances of IIS Express running. But only one can use port 12345, so we get the following error message:

#### Error

`An error occurred launching IIS Express. Unable to launch the configured Visual Studio Development Web server.Port '12345' is in use.`

## Question

Is it somehow possible to run and debug multiple website projects inside a single website under IIS Express? Or can we control the application pool? Or ...?

### Remarks

You can find a simple example with the described problem at https://github.com/EdwinEngelen/IISExpressDemo.

This might not be the best practice for modern .NET application, but the application we're working on here is still on .NET Framework 4.7.2. Migrating to SDK style projects (with help of [MSBuild.SDK.SystemWeb](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSBuild.SDK.SystemWeb)) is part of our migration path to .NET.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Several things you should know: 1) https://github.com/CZEMacLeod/MSBuild.SDK.SystemWeb is not supported by Microsoft, so use it at your own risks and things can break. 2) VS moved away from using the same applicationHost.config file for all web projects in the same solution, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/getting-started/features.html#add-iis-express-from-visual-studio-2015-2017-2019-solution-file 3) IIS Express is a single process server. 4) ASP.NET Core projects cannot run in the same IIS worker process (in-process hosting) by design. 5) You should use full IIS and the old project format.

Comment: 1) I know github.com/CZEMacLeod/MSBuild.SDK.SystemWeb is not supported. The problem also occurs with brand new clean projects. See linked demo on GitHub.

2) I'm well aware of the per solution 'applicationhost.config' files in the .vs folder.

3) IIS Express being a single process server is exactly the reason I want all sites running inside the same application pool.

4) It does work with IIS Express and the old format. I'm now trying to switch to the new format.

Comment: The only way you can switth to the new format is if you using .net core and MVC websites, this will certainly not work with older web forms sites which NEVER had .net core support.  And this will not work if you using .net framework. So, no, you can't out of the blue use some new format designed for .net core and use .net core for older .net webform sites. If the older sites are MVC sites, then you FIRST need to convert those older sites to run as .net core sites (from .net framework) and THEN you can use the newer project config formats.